# Add Numbers to MySQL, HTML table in order

Tags: php, html, mysql

I will try my best to explain what I am trying to do. Hopefully you can help me out. I have a database that holds links, these links are displayed in a table. I have the entries output properly in order from Points, but I am trying to add a rank number to the side so it says 1, 2, 3, 4, etc going down the page per entry. 
Here is my attempt.

```html
<table width = "1000" style='table-layout:fixed;'>
    <tr>
        // These are the numbers I need to add
        <th>Rank</th>
        // All these work fine.
        <th>Host</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
        <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)):;?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row1[0]; ?></td>
        <td><a href="<?php echo $row1['Location']; ?>"><?php echo $row1[1]; ?></a></td>
        <td><?php echo $row1[2]; ?></td>
    </tr>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

Hopefully you understand what I am trying to do, if you need any more information let me know.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: you need to "COUNT()" those in SELECT or in a `for` loop. Good luck.

Comment: @Saty Saw your comment about *"Is it valid syntax of loop with semicolon at while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)):;<-- ???* (in the now-deleted answer). Yeah that's what I said in their other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/37244399/ yet they still say it works. *Hah, yeah right.* So I think we're all getting trolled.

Comment: I feel like we're getting trolled because how hard is it to add an incrementing index to the loop. ` $i ++; echo $i; `

Comment: @Wobbles I'd say you are *right on the money* ;-) about your the beginning of your comment.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for updating my knowledge!!!

Comment: @Saty You're most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

you mean? :

```
<?php $rankId=0; while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){ ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?=$rankId++ ?></td>
    <td><?=$row1[0] ?></td>
    <td><a href="<?=$row1['Location'] ?>"><?= $row1[1] ?></a></td>
    <td><?=$row1[2] ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
```